# Why won't my .war start after deploying to tomcat 7, but running an embedded server works fine?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, deployment

I am able to run my app on an embedded server with `mvn clean install tomcat7:run` successfully. I can also deploy successfully by running `mvn tomcat7:depoly` or `mvn cargo:redeploy`, but the app fails with the following exception:

```
Mar 18, 2013 3:57:18 PM com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry banner
INFO: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
15:57:19.183 [localhost-startStop-4] ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accountDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: private void com.application.DAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.application.data.MyEntity"/>
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) ~[spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:977) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1655) [catalina.jar:7.0.37]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [na:1.6.0_41]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [na:1.6.0_41]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: private void com.application.DAO.setSessionFactory(org.hibernate.SessionFactory); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.application.data.MyEntity"/>
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:601) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-business.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.application.data.MyEntity"/>
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:558) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.application.data.MyEntity"/>
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseMappingElement(Configuration.java:1597) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.parseSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1552) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1531) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1505) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1440) ~[hibernate-3.2.1.ga.jar:3.2.1.ga]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:283) ~[spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485) ~[spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar:3.2.2.RELEASE]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
```

And here are the relevant configuration files:

**applicationContext-business.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Component scan to find all Spring components -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.application">
    </context:component-scan>

    <!-- Data Source: HSQLDB + c3p0 connection pooling -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close"
          p:acquireIncrement="1"
          p:maxStatements="0"
          p:numHelperThreads="3">

        <property name="driverClass" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:hsqldb:src/main/resources/schema/db"/>
        <property name="user" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>

        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="3"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="50"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="200"/>

    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate Session Factory  -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />

        <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <!-- The packages that contain our Hibernate model classes -->
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.application.data</value>
                <value>com.application.dao</value>
                <value>com.application.service</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate transaction management -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="onStartupBean" class="com.application.StartUp">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="platformTransactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Connection handler: C3P0 -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>


        <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- Cache settings -->
        <!--
        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
            org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
        </property>
        -->
        <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
        <property name="cache.use_structured_entries">false</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="default_batch_fetch_size">8</property>
        <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
        <property name="jdbc.batch_size">10</property>

        <!-- List all the annotated classes we're using -->
        <mapping class="com.application.data.MyEntity"/>
        <mapping class="com.application.data.EntityOne"/>
        <mapping class="com.application.data.EntityTwo"/>
        <mapping class="com.application.data.EntityThree"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Why will this only run on an embedded tomcat server?

Comment: Did you setup hibernate twice? Eg: you've setup one on your server, but you include it again on your war? If so your app might picked the wrong hibernate (possibly different version) -- hence causing the error

Comment: I don't believe I've setup Hibernate twice, but thanks for the suggestion. Is there a quick way to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`, but with Hiberate 3.2.4.  Either use Hibernate 4.0.0 or greater, or use the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean` instead.